# How can I find an $\varepsilon$ environment to disprove $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\{{\sqrt{n}}\}) = 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-explanation

Prove:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}(\{{\sqrt{n}}\}) \neq 0
$$

It's obvious that $\{\sqrt{n}\} = 0$ when $\sqrt{n} \in \mathbb{N}$ and
$1\gt$ $\{\sqrt{n}\}$ $\gt 0$ when $\sqrt{n} \notin \mathbb{N}$.
I have to find an infinite group of numbers that each one of them is greater than $\ 0+\varepsilon$. That's how I define an  $\varepsilon$ environment for $\\0$ and disprove it. How can I find it? thanks.

Comment: $$\left\{\sqrt{m^2+m}\right\}\approx \frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit more subtle than it looks at first glance. Here's how I would approach a problem like this: I know that $\{\sqrt{n}\}=0$ when $n=k^2$ and when $n=(k+1)^2$.  Since I want to maximize it, I should probably look at the 'worst-case scenario': $\{\sqrt{n}\}$ is increasing between squares, then drops back to zero only to increase again; so what if I look at $n=(k+1)^2-1$?  This is an infinite subsequence of numbers trending to $\infty$, and you should be able to show a bound away from $0$ for $\{\sqrt{(k+1)^2-1}\}$.  (Note that $\lfloor\sqrt{(k+1)^2-1}\rfloor=k$, so you just have to find a lower bound on the distance $\sqrt{(k+1)^2-1}-k$.)

Comment: Thank you. Do I find the lower bound by guessing from the tendency and then proving it?

Comment: Exactly. You can also go from the other direction: look at $\lceil(k+\frac12)^2\rceil$ and find an explicit expression, note that it's between $k^2$ and $(k+1)^2$ for all (sufficiently large) $k$, and etc.

Comment: I have to find the range of $\\{\sqrt{\lceil(k+\frac12)^2\rceil}}$ right? I've tried to solve this for hours.

Comment: I mean the range of $\\{\{\sqrt{\lceil(k+\frac12)^2\rceil}\}}$

Comment: Did you mean to : $\\{\sqrt{\lceil(k+\frac12)^2\rceil}} = k + 0.5 + t => \varepsilon > 0.5$ ?

Comment: @MorHaham Yes. You should be able to write $\lceil(k+\frac12)^2\rceil$ as an explicit (integer) expression in $k$, then prove that this is $\lt (k+1)^2$ and so $\lfloor\sqrt{\lceil(k+\frac12)^2\rceil}\rfloor=k$. Since you know that the $\sqrt{}$ is at least $k+\frac12$, this gives you an $\epsilon$ of at least $\frac12$.

Comment: How do you prove that $\sqrt{(k+1)^2-1}$ is not natural?

Comment: It would have to be a natural number between $k$ and $k+1$, because $\sqrt{}$ is monotonic.

Comment: We didn’t learn functions yet. Even then I think I should prove it formally.

Comment: Nevermind you meant to monotonic squences. I still don’t understand how it exactly proves that it’s not natural for all n.

Comment: Because $a\lt b\implies \sqrt{a}\lt\sqrt{b}$ and vice versa (this is what I mean by monotonic). If $\sqrt{(k+1)^2-1}$ is a natural number, then it is a natural number strictly between $k$ and $k+1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: But then I have to prove that the natural numbers are not dense in (k, k+1). Is it an axiom?

Comment: With all due respect, I'm starting to wonder if you're being deliberately obtuse here. What definition of "natural number" are you using that you have to ask if there are any natural numbers between, e.g., 7 and 8?

Comment: We didn't define natural numbers formally in the course and I am not sure how deep I have to go with proofs. I've looked at the formal definition in Wikipedia and I'm still not sure how to disprove that natural numbers are exist in (k,k+1).I know it's kind of ridiculous question for you but I'm just curious. Please accept my apologies because I see you are starting to be impatient with my questions.

Answer (score 1):

We can try the following: since $\;\{\sqrt n\}=\sqrt n-\left\lfloor\sqrt n\right\rfloor\;$, we can take the subsequence for all the indexes of the form $\;n^2+n+1\;$ , i.e.: $\;3,7,13,\ldots\;$ , and thus we have

$$\{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}\}=\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-\left\lfloor \sqrt{n^2+n+1}\right\rfloor\;$$

But we **always** have that $\;\left\lfloor\sqrt{n^2+n+1}\right\rfloor=n\;$ (*why?*) , so

$$\;\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-\left\lfloor\sqrt{n^2+n+1}\right\rfloor=\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-n\;$$

and thus this partial limit is

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}+n+1}=$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac1n}{\sqrt{1+\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}}+1+\frac1n}=\frac1{1+1}=\frac12$$

Comment: Oh my...It took me some time to understand this brilliant proof. I still don't understand how could I find it by myself though.

Comment: @MorHaham Don't worry too much about that. It's experience...and dealing with mathematics constantly. The idea was to use the expression $\;x=\lfloor x\rfloor +\{x\}\;$ and make a little research about it...and it came up pretty nice.